# Property 'positions' does not exist on type

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have this interface:

```js
interface ScrollPositionRestore {
  event: Event;
  positions: { [K: number]: number };
  trigger: 'imperative' | 'popstate';
  idToRestore: number;
}
```

And this RxJS scan operator:

```js
filter(
  (event) =>
    event instanceof NavigationStart || event instanceof NavigationEnd,
),
scan<Event, ScrollPositionRestore>((acc, event) => ({
  event,
  positions: {
    ...acc.positions,
    ...(event instanceof NavigationStart
      ? {
          [event.id]: this.contentArea.nativeElement.scrollTop,
        }
      : {}),
  },
  trigger:
    event instanceof NavigationStart
      ? event.navigationTrigger
      : acc.trigger,
  idToRestore:
    (event instanceof NavigationStart &&
      event.restoredState &&
      event.restoredState.navigationId + 1) ||
    acc.idToRestore,
})),
```

But I'm getting several TS errors:
[image]

`positions`is declared on the `ScrollPositionRestore` interface, so why is TS not using that?

Comment: Does it exists on `Event_2`?

Comment: When dealing with a union type you either have to narrow the type with compiler legible runtime checks like `in`, `instanceof`, etc or the property has to be present on both types in the union.

Comment: @JaredSmith I've updated the question with a filter operator that should do that

Comment: You need to edit the question to be a minimal reproducible example. Give us something we can run, otherwise we can't really help you other than with generic advice like my earlier comment.

Answer (score 2):

Using the *scan* operator can be tricky.   The type of the accumulator parameter will either the accumlator type unioned with the source type, or the accumlator type unioned with the type of the seed (the second parameter to scan).

Since you're not providing a seed, the type of *acc* is properly being inferred as *Event_2 | ScrollPositionRestore*.  The syntax error appears, since *positions* is not a property on *Event_2* and therefore cannot be on the unioned type.

To get around this you should rewrite the call to scan and provide a seed that's the same type as the accumlator type.

```
filter(
  (event): event is NavigationStart | NavigationEnd => // I like my filters typed.
    event instanceof NavigationStart || event instanceof NavigationEnd,
),
scan<Event, ScrollPositionRestore, ScrollPositionRestore>((acc, event) => ({
  /* do the same assignment as before */
}), { positions: {} }) // <-- seed
```

It's not clear it works this way from the [documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/scan), however if you look at the [source](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/0a4e8bf12b59b80b8012b8e8da044d6b48d865f5/src/internal/operators/scan.ts#L6-L7), you'll see that for the function overloads that provide a seed, the return type is either just the accumulator type when no seed type is provided or the union of the accumulator and seed type when the seed type is provided.